# Mysql pivot table with variable length of columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have the following table in mysql

```
user_id | email 
1 | primary@test.com 
1 | secondary@test.com 
2 | email@test.com
```

what query in mysql need to run to get the following pivot table?
user_id | primary_email | secondary_email

```
1 | primary@test.com | secondary@test.com 
2 | email@test.com
```

The column number for email are not standard maybe 1, maybe 2, ... maybe x

Comment: Do you really need to pivote them into their own columns? Couldn't you just use `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: In which way  you can define   the primary and the secondary email ?

Comment: I'd like to avoid group_concat() for now there isn't a real distinction between primary and secondary, I just assign them in the order they're retrieved. in the future I might add a "type" field to the original table